# Does EmberJS have an event which get called after a Handlebars-view has been updated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js

This has boggled me for some time, but I managed to keep pushing it forward. Unfortunately, the time has come I really need this.

My question is: Does EmberJS/Handlebars offer an event which gets called when a view is updated and visible in the DOM?

I need to use this event to run some jQuery stuff like addClass, sortable, etc. I've tried using the Live jQuery plugin but it doesn't work with Handlebars. On top of that I assume said event is already in place somewhere, I just can't seem find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you had a look at `willInsertElement`, `didInsertElement`, and `willRerender` methods in `Ember.View`? Also, there are plenty of post here on S.O. that deal with integrating jQuery plugins and frameworks with Ember.

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/views/view.js#L1250-1267

**edit/update**

After a little back and fourth in the comments, the final solution was to use `Ember.run.next`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/SsRuX/

Comment: I saw those, problem with these events is that `willInsertElement` and `didInsertElement` are only called once when the view as added to the DOM using `appendTo`, not when it updates. `willRerender` does indeed fire, but before anything is added to the DOM, making calling jQuery calls not do anything.

Comment: Would you happen to have links to said posts on StackOverflow?

Comment: What about `afterRender`? How is the view updating? Is it a property change? If so you just need to observe that property. Is it some event, like a mouse event? Do you have any code you can share? It'll really help in point you in the right direction...

Comment: `afterRender` only runs once the view is added to the DOM for the first time, not after that anymore. I made a very simplified JSFiddle example for you, the jQuery code in (now) `afterRender` should fire every time `update` has been called and the DOM updated: http://jsfiddle.net/nqd9c/3/

Comment: Oh okay. Well a quick way to modify that is to use `Ember.run.next`. See: [http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/SsRuX/](http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/SsRuX/). Is that what you were looking for to happen?

Comment: THat seems to work yes. If that is guaranteed to wait after the DOM is actually updated I'm happy with it. Shame there isn't an actual event like `afterRender` and such.

Comment: Yes. `Ember.run.next` runs after all bindings and rendering in whichever runloop cycle you're in and before the start of the next runloop.

Comment: I quickly hacked it into my actual project, works fine! I can probably create some nice wrapper around it so I can use Handlerbar-helpers to trigger specific jQuery code :) Thank you!

Comment: Ember.run.next is not reliable for me, somethings the DOM is not updated.